# Using Windows function SendMessage results in linking error with MSVC but not with MinGW

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, visual-c++

I'am using the Windows function SendMessage in one of my functions.

If I compile with MinGW everything is fine.

If I compile with MSVC2013 I'm getting this linking error

```
myClass.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SendMessageW@16 referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall ...
```

Why is that?

Comment: mingw implicitly links some libs, you need to lib them yourself in msvc

Comment: Hmm... Okay, which could that be?

Comment: @avb Look up `SendMessage` in Visual Studio's builtin help and you'll find out.

Comment: Include the lib mentioned on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
 #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: `"user32.dll"` is a DLL, not the import library. The import library is `"user32.lib"`. Alternatively you can omit the file extension altogether and simply use `#pragma comment(lib, "user32")`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, mistyped .lib for .dll. Of course, the linker directive should accept .lib file, thanks to Alf for editing.

Answer (score 3):

Visual C++ only links in `kernel32.dll` by default.

g++ additionally links in a number of other DLLs (Windows API sub-libraries). Exactly what depends on the options.

Relevant line from the `specs` file with the Nuwen distro of MinGW g++ 4.9.1:

```
%{pg:-lgmon} %{pthread:-lpthread} %{!no-pthread: } %{mwindows:-lgdi32 -lcomdlg32} -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32
```